# Spark: normalize each row of a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark DataFrame, which looks like the following

```
df.show()
+------+------+------+
|  col1|  col2|  col3|
+------+------+------+
|   5.0|   5.0|   0.0|
|   2.0|   3.0|   5.0|
|   4.0|   1.0|  10.0|
+------+------+------+
```

I would like to normalize each individual rows, such that after the operation, the new columns would look like:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|new_col1|new_col2|new_col3|
+--------+--------+--------+
|     0.5|     0.5|     0.0|
|     0.2|     0.3|     0.5|
|0.266667|0.066667|0.666667|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

More formally, the operation I would like to apply is:

for each row,

```
    new_col_i = col_i / (col_1 + col_2 + col_3)
```

I will need to do this programmatically instead of listing all the columns, as my DataFrame has many columns.

### Current solution:

The current solution I think of is to create a column to represent the sum of all the entries for each row, then divide each column by that sum column.

```
var newDF = df.withColumn("total", df.columns.map(c => col(c)).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2))

for (c <- Array("col1", "col2", "col3")) {
    newDF = newDF.withColumn("normalized_" + c, col(c).divide(col("total")))
}
newDF.show()

+----+----+----+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|col1|col2|col3|total|    normalized_col1|    normalized_col2|   normalized_col3|
+----+----+----+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 5.0| 5.0| 0.0| 10.0|                0.5|                0.5|               0.0|
| 2.0| 3.0| 5.0| 10.0|                0.2|                0.3|               0.5|
| 4.0| 1.0|10.0| 15.0|0.26666666666666666|0.06666666666666667|0.6666666666666666|
+----+----+----+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

**Any alternative to make the code more succinct?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is correct, and can't be improved too much. You can get rid of the non-idiomatic use of `var` by replacing the for-loop with a `foldLeft`, and use some more syntactic sugar all around, but other than that it would remain the same:

```
val withTotal = df.withColumn("total", df.columns.map(col).reduce(_ + _))

val result = df.columns.foldLeft(withTotal) {
  (tmp, c) => tmp.withColumn(s"new_$c", $"$c" / $"total")
}
  .drop(df.columns: _*)
  .drop("total")
```

Comment: Thanks @Tzach Zohar! I was indeed looking for some functional operations to replace the for-loop style operation.

Comment: a minor question: why do you need case in line 3?

Comment: The case here is useful to "unapply" the tuple of (DataFrame, Column) and name its parts individually. Alternatively, I could have written something like `tuple => tuple._1.withColumn(s"new_${tuple._2}", $"${tuple._2}" / $"total")` - but as you can see that's much less readable.

Comment: but foldLeft can also take an anonymous function (tmp, c) => tmp.withColumn(s"new_$c", $"$c" / $"total"). Do I miss anything about it?

Comment: Oh - yes, of course, sorry. This is a very old answer and I replied a bit too quickly :) The case keyword can be omitted in this case

Comment: it is indeed an old question, lol. Anyway, thanks for the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking how to do the row-wise normalization in PySpark, the code below worked for me:

```
new_df = df.withColumn('total', sum(df[col] for col in df.columns))
my_schema = StructType([StructField(col, DoubleType(), True) for col in df.columns])
result  = new_df.rdd.map(lambda x: [100.00 * x[i]/x[len(x) -1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]).toDF(schema = my_schema)
result.show()
```

`+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|        col1      |         col2   |         col3     |
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|              50.0|             50.0|              0.0|
|              20.0|             30.0|             50.0|
|26.666666666666668|6.666666666666667|66.66666666666667|
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+`